# WCF ServiceHost access rights

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-7

I get the following error when going through the WCF tutorial.

HTTP could not register URL http://+:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).

Is this something caused by a restriction on Windows 7?

Comment: You can find a lot of useful information on this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx). Hey also provides a nice GUI tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP could not register URL http://+:8000/HelloWCF/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727293/http-could-not-register-url-http-8000-hellowcf-your-process-does-not-have)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The issue is that the URL is being blocked from being created by Windows.

Steps to fix:
Run command prompt as an administrator.
Add the URL to the ACL

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service user=mylocaluser
```

Comment: Glad you fixed that. What did the "+" mean?

Comment: I have a hunch that it means a generic local IP.

Comment: Note: You pretty much have to enter url=http://+:port/path exactly. url=http://address:port/path did not work for me, as you would think it might. Also note that you have to use the network server as your user ("NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", if that's what your service's installer is set to.

Comment: Any way yo do this without needing an Administrator access?

Comment: And for older versions of Windows like Server 2003 there's useful detail of what to do [in this blog](http://dmitrygusev.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/host-wcf-service-in-windows-service.html) and not quite so useful [on the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)

Comment: using my account for the user didn't work.  Worked with user=Everyone

Answer (score 91):

If you are running via the IDE, running as administrator should help.  To do this locate the Visual Studio 2008/10 application icon, right click it and select "Run as administrator"

Comment: Not really a 'much better' solution @Liam - administrator privileges in a dev environment in a corporate setup could give you many more permissions to do dangerous things. A much easier solution, sure, but with power comes responsibility ...

Comment: Original solution also required execution as administrator - granted for a smaller period of time, and of course you need to be aware what you are doing from a security context.

Comment: so, anyway to do this without admin privileges?

Comment: Perfect. I was running a program from IDE that needed to register a URL on another machine and running as administrator worked perfectly.

Answer (score 36):

Another solution is to use the address

http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/YOUR_ADDRESS .

.NET Framework (3.5) automatically register this address (http://*:8732/Design_Time_Addresses) for debugging scope. This is useful when you need to host services inside visual studio for debugging or testing. Don't use this on production...

Comment: Some sites refer to port 8731 instead of 8732.

Comment: @DaviFiamenghi As long as .net 3.5 is installed it should work. But I never tried. Usually I consider a test like this an integration test so I don't run it on TFS, I only run unit tests on TFS.

Comment: @NenadDobrilovic Mine uses 8733 :). But that is not important.

Comment: Our server is using http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ and I'd have never known to look for it without your answer, thanks. Also, [Bob's tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx) showed all of the addresses that were permissioned - that's how I discovered it was 8733. Thanks

Answer (score 31):

Open a command prompt as the administrator and you write below command to add your URL:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8000/YourServiceLibrary/YourService user=Everyone
```

Answer (score 3):

Open Visual Studio as an Administrator..
It will run.

Comment: I had the same problem with nunit-gui. Ran as administrator, all good.

Comment: I have the same problem vs 2013 and running as admin doesn't work

Comment: why i need admin why can't i run as standard user?

Answer (score 0):

Other option that work is ..,

If you change de indentity in application pool, you can run the code, the idea is change the aplication pool execution account for one account with more privileges,

For more details use this blog

https://letrasandnumeros.com/2017/11/27/http-could-not-register-url-http-80-hellowcf-your-process-does-not-have-access-rights-to-this-namespace/

Answer (score -2):

I am working on Windows Vista. Even i faced the same problem but when i tried to run VS 2008 with administrative privileges, the issue resolved and my service was up and running. :)

Answer (score -2):

Running Visual Studio as administrator could fix the issue, but if you use Visual Studio with for example TortoiseSVN, you cannot commit any changes. Another possible solution would be to run the service as administrator and the rest Visual Studio as local user.

Answer (score -3):

Please open your Visual Studio as administrator:

[image]