# I'm having trouble launching my WCF service using a console application. What can be wrong?

Tags: wcf, console-application, endpoint

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using BankServiceClient.BankServiceReference;

namespace BankServiceClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/Simple");
            Type instanceType = typeof(BankServiceReference.BankClient);
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(instanceType,baseAddress);

            using (host)
            {
                Type contractType = typeof(BankServiceReference.IBank);
                string relativeAddress = "BankService";
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(contractType, new BasicHttpBinding(), relativeAddress);

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                host.Close();
            }

            /*
             * Consuming a WCF Service and using its method.
             */

            //IBank proxy = new BankClient();

            //double number = proxy.GetBalance(1234);

            //Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

First, a couple of questions:

1. The 'baseAddress' attribute, what exactly **is** it? When I launched my service using the default F5 (no console application) the service launched on a random port on localHost. How can I write in an exact number and expect it to go there? Confused at this one.
2. What **is** the relativeAddress attribute? It says BankService but what should I write in that attribute? Confused at this one as well.

Here's the exact error message I get when I try to run this Console application:

> HTTP could not register URL
>   http://+:8000/Simple/. Your process
>   does not have access rights to this
>   namespace (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353
>   for details).

Answer (score 0):

First is your client project set to be the start up project?

And to answer your questions.

1)  baseAddress ([URI Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx)) is the base address for your hosted service.  I am thinking you are launching some other project.

2) You have two options on configuring endpoints([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx)).  Relative and Absolute.  The way you did it will take your base and appends your relative -> http://localhost:8000/Simple/BankService

Lastly to fix your hosting issue see this SO link:

[WCF ServiceHost access rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885744/wcf-servicehost-access-rights)