# Self-Host WCF Service Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I am getting the below error when I execute the application.
[image: error]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why can't I see the attached image??? I have attached image of the error.

Comment: Select the error text, copy it, paste it into a search engine and find the answer. For example: [HTTP could not register URL http://+:8000/HelloWCF/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727293/http-could-not-register-url-http-8000-hellowcf-your-process-does-not-have).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Kindly find the answer below.

Comment: This question already has been answered on this site, see my link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you don't have permission to host your service in that namespace. Right-click on Visual Studio and `Run as Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7 or 2008 and above use this command from administrator command prompt

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080 user=DOMAIN\user
```

where user is the user or service account that will run the WCF service.
For XP or windows 2003 you will have to use the htpcfg tool. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)

The service doesn't need local admin rights but an administrator needs to give the right to reserver the http url namespace as an installation step.