# System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http::8080

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding, self-hosting

I have created my first self-hosted WCF service. I hosted it in a C# console app but it throws an error:

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http: 8080

When I run Visual Studio 2013 as administrator, then it works well, but not if I don't. So any way to get it done automatically instead of starting VS as an ADMIN?

So far I created a `HelloService` class library in which I added a WCF service which consists of an interface `IHelloService` and `HelloService`.

`IHelloService`:

```
namespace HelloService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        String GetMsg();
    }
}
```

`HelloService`:

```
namespace HelloService
{
    public class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public String GetMsg()
        {
            return "Service Accessed";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a C# console app `HelloServiceHost` which has an `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors >
        <behavior name="MexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloService.HelloService" 
               behaviorConfiguration="MexBehaviour" >
        <endpoint 
            address="HelloService" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="HelloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint 
            address="HelloService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            contract="HelloService.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint 
            address="mex" 
            binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8081/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and program.cs file:

```
using HelloService;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace HelloServiceHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService.HelloService)))
            {
                sh.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host Started @"+ System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString());
                sh.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I followed a video tutorial exactly but it's not working why ?

I am using VS 2013, .net 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP could not register URL http://+:8000/HelloWCF/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727293/http-could-not-register-url-http-8000-hellowcf-your-process-does-not-have)

Answer (score 36):

Start the cmd as Administrator and enter:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```

this worked for me.

Comment: For bonus points, remove the permissions afterwards with this -- netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:8080/MyUri

Answer (score 22):

I ran into the same problem on a different project.

The problem is that binding to a tcp port requires administrative privileges. There's a couple ways to deal with this.

1. Keep an administrative command prompt open. Then you can just run the console app directly.
2. (As you suggested) run VS as admin. This is absolutely necessary only when debugging your app.
3. Create an application manifiest file, specifying requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator". See [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) for more details.

Comment: Binding to a TCP port does not require administrative privileges.  Rather, it is to do with the underlying Windows HTTP API, which is managing the TCP server socket for you.

Answer (score 9):

Root path URL (http://+:8080/) permissions are needed in your case:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%
```

show all URL reservations:

```
netsh http show urlacl | FIND "URL"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you ran into this error while starting the service on Windows Service, you can check the account on your process installer.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "WCFWindowsServiceSample";
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP's question was about a console application, not a windows service

Comment: Consider updating your answer to provide a complete answer to the question.