# Wcf-Service Post Method(Json Formatted)

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am developing a wcf rest service for our business requirement. But while I am using Web Invoke method for POST I am getting an error. That Error is not happening if I use stream as input parameter. My question is how I can use my own defined class instead of stream for Json type data. Please give some code samples for the same.

Below are my code samples

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "Addnewclaim")]
    Addclaimreport Addnewclaim(Stream JSONData);
```

Inplementation:

```
public Addclaimreport Addnewclaim(Stream JSONData)
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(JSONData);
    string data = read.ReadToEnd();
    read.Close();
    read.Dispose();
    object yourOjbect = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(data);
    Dictionary<string, object> accident_details = (Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)yourOjbect)["Accident_Details"];  
    Dictionary<string, object> Driver_details = (Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)yourOjbect)["Drv_Details"];  
    Dictionary<string, object> Genaral_details = (Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)yourOjbect)["Drv_Details"];  
    string Acc_dtls = Genaral_details["Accident_Details"].ToString();
    return new Addclaimreport();
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23562698/3445604 for some clues.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to answer of this enter link description 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef4cfee3-4d96-44a5-9fa1-ebafdff9bee3/wcf-stream-with-more-than-one-parameter

Use "code" feature next time because your post is not easy to understand like this !

found solution from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
     void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request); 
}
[MessageContract]
public class DownloadRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string FileName;
}

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    { 
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }   
}
```