# WCF HTTP self-hosting without admin?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is there any way of starting a HTTP WCF service from a regular, non-admin application manually? All I want is my regular desktop application to listen on a port where some things can be controlled remotely.

I could go the manual route and use my own TcpListener, parse HTTP (or any other protocol), go through some reflection, then respond back on TCP, but I'd like to use WCF to avoid boilerplate.

Comment: What leads you to believe that running a WCF service requires admin rights?

Comment: The exception that I'm getting (HTTP could not register URL http://+:39483/hello/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace) as well as [many other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727293/http-could-not-register-url-http-8000-hellowcf-your-process-does-not-have) questions that are somewhat related to mine. In my situation it's not feasible to be admin or use netsh. I can listen on ports and would like to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial workaround is to use http://localhost:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/ if that's acceptable in your situation (not in mine though). This URL magically doesn't require additional permissions. [source](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/06/11/developing-as-a-non-admin-testing-wcf-services.aspx/)