# Geting Error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: c#

I am Creating a smart Device Application for my client in Visual studio 2008. I Have Create a web service to get stock data from actual database and save in windows ce Device Compact database on a button click event of smart device application. Here is my code:

```
    private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceAgent.InventorySev ws = new InvetoryDevice.ServiceAgent.InventorySev();

        AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(ServiceCallback);
        ws.BeginGetInventoryData(cb, ws);
    }

    private void ServiceCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ServiceAgent.InventorySev ws = (ServiceAgent.InventorySev)ar.AsyncState;
        DataTable dt = ws.EndGetInventoryData(ar);
    }
```

I am geting Error:

```
   DataTable dt = ws.EndGetInventoryData(ar);
```

Error:

```
    System.Net.WebException was unhandled
    Message="Unable to connect to the remote server"
    StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.finishGetResponse()
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
            at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
            at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters, WebClientAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doAsyncInvoke(Object asyncResultAsObject)
            at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
            at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
    InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            Message="No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
            ErrorCode=10061
            NativeErrorCode=10061
        StackTrace:
                at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectNoCheck(EndPoint remoteEP)
                at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
                at System.Net.Connection.doConnect(IPEndPoint ep)
                at System.Net.Connection.connect(Object ignored)
                at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
                at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Comment: Could you show the code of your `webservice`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3446](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0)

Comment: My Web service Code is:  [WebMethod]
        public DataTable GetInventoryData()
        {
            BuyTableAdapter ta = new BuyTableAdapter();
            InvDataSet.BuyDataTable buy = ta.GetCurrnetStock();
            return buy;
        }

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be a duplication. Regardless, your problem is not in your code, but with the connection to the database.

Quoted from [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3446](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0?rq=1)

> "Actively refused it" means that the host sent a reset instead of an
>   ack when you tried to connect. It is therefore not a problem in your
>   code. Either there is a firewall blocking the connection or the
>   process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port,
>   this may be because it is not running at all or because it is
>   listening on a different port.
>
> once you start the process hosting your service try netstat -anb
>   (requires admin privileges) to verify that it is running and listening
>   on the expected port.