# Copy image from URL using PHP

Tags: php, image, url

I want to copy image from a url to my server using PHP.
I saw this answer [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php)

and Tried this :

```
<?php

$url = 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/548412_147785902099377_260065314_n.jpg?oh=5c97dcd58931398e501666daee4c4ae8&oe=5457AC73&__gda__=1414911437_494ad1af138ee7670f89f4a6ba8b6d06';
$img = 'flower.jpg';
copy($url, $img);

?>
```

But i got the following error :

```
failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

My php version is 5.4 and in my php.ini `allow_url_fopen=On`

I cant find how to fix this, any clever suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can use `file_get_contents`? <edit> As in the accepted answer of the question you linked to.

Comment: That server doesn't like you trying to access its files that way. [See this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0) - in the meantime, take off the `s` in `https` and see if it helps.

Comment: @CompuChip - That's exactly the same underlying mechanism.

Comment: @Deryck same Error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I can grab it with plain `curl` at the command line:

```
curl "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/548412_147785902099377_260065314_n.jpg?oh=5c97dcd58931398e501666daee4c4ae8&oe=5457AC73&__gda__=1414911437_494ad1af138ee7670f89f4a6ba8b6d06" > bill.jpg
```

Maybe you can use php's `system` to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use file_put_contents instead of copy.use below code

```
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: Same Error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

How about using curl, you can then write directly to file.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/548412_147785902099377_260065314_n.jpg?oh=5c97dcd58931398e501666daee4c4ae8&oe=5457AC73&__gda__=1414911437_494ad1af138ee7670f89f4a6ba8b6d06';

$fp = fopen ('./flower.jpg', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'YourBot.0.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  false); //required!
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  false); //required!
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Strange...No problems here ive tested it and it works. Im wounding if fb is actually blocking the host your trying it from, If your testing this locally, check that you can at least view the image in your browser.

Comment: also check you have curl installed