# How to configure TopShelf client and host on LAN network?

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, topshelf, servicemodelex

I tried this tutorial for .NET TopShelf: http://lourenco.co.za/blog/2013/08/wcf-windows-service-using-topshelf-and-servicemodelex/ and everything works fine on localhost, but when I run Client app on other PC with host IP in app.config aplication return an exception in Program.cs in Client app in line:

```
var response = proxy.Service.Introduce(request);
```

The error message says: "tcp error code 10061 no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

I've got windows firewall off. What can I do to connect two computers in LAN network using TopShelf?

Comment: Have you checked if the server machine has the port unblocked?
Also it sometimes helps for the service to be running in Network Service.

if not I'm assuming you've already seen this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9695442/933007

Comment: Yes i've seen this. I have got firewall turned off, on server pc netstat shows my service on: 0.0.0.0:500123 [WCFService.WidnowsService.vshost.exe] and it still doesn't work. Telnet on client can't see my server. Is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss, the only other thing I can think of is, are you able to connect to the pc normally? and are the 2 computers on the same workgroup/domain/subnet. Also make sure you are running with NotworkService host and not local service host

Comment: I suggest you look at the following - user running the service, firewall on both PCs. also, your port number is 500123? That seems like it's out of range of any port number.