# Pass parameters to C# Http client post

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am learning to create a RESTful API with a client, but am struggling with passing user input to the post. My controller is fine as I can send data to db (tested with Swagger) but on the client side the debugger is giving me an error on my PostAsJsonAsync. I think it probably has to do with the routing. Here is my post code from my client:

```
static async Task AddAsync(ForumPost fp)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7656/");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
                      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // HTTP POST
            ForumPost thePost = new ForumPost() { 
                                    Subject = fp.Subject, 
                                    Message = fp.Message};
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("post", thePost);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Uri uri = response.Headers.Location;
                Console.WriteLine("URI for new resource: " + uri.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and the relevant bit of the controller

```
[HttpPost]
// POST: api/Forum
[Route("post")]
public void PostNewMessage (string subject, string message)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ForumPost p = new ForumPost(subject, message);
        db.ForumPosts.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have looked around at various different but similar questions here on SO but struggling to understand. I have tried putting placeholders in the route but maybe I implemented it incorrectly? (that's if that is even the correct way to be thinking!) If anyone could help me out on this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Web API action parameters are simple types like strings, the [parameter binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) mechanism assumes they are coming from the query string. To infer that the values should come from the request body, just use your `ForumPost` class directly as your parameter instead of the individual string values:

```
[HttpPost]
// POST: api/Forum
[Route("post")]
public void PostNewMessage(ForumPost p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ForumPosts.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Also note that `ForumPost` needs a parameterless constructor in order for the framework to know how to create an instance. Define it like this and you should be good:

```
public class ForumPost 
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Todd,Thanks for reply. I tried to implement what you said but to no avail. I'm not sure that this was the (biggest!) problem anyway. Even when I hard code a new post in the client and pass it to PostAsJsonAsync I am getting an error. It is a socket error exception: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:23226\r\n...etc

Comment: That's a networking issue and if you google that exception message you'll find no shortage of results, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0) for example.  Though I'm confident my suggested fix was also needed to get this working.

Comment: Thanks again Todd, Simple typo in the end - wrong port number. Yes, I have now implemented your suggestions and my post is now working.