# No connection could be made because the target computer the actively refused

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i am kinda new working with Asp.net Rest and i dont know how to solve this, i already read many articles at stackoverflow and no one solved my problem, i tryed firewall i tryed the configurations on internet option and other things, i think the problem can be related to something that is confusing me, do i need to run the webservice before i run my client application ?? how to do it? because what i did was just programming my rest application then i created my asp.net mvc application where i connect to the rest service with this helper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Net.Http;
namespace ClienteMvcProdutos.Helpers
{
    public static class WebApiHttpClient
    {
        public const string WebApiBaseAddress = "http://localhost:25426/";
        public static HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiBaseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

already checked ports and they matched, already changed ports and it still dont work im kinda desesperating :S here is my stacktrace

> [SocketException (0x274d): Nenhuma ligação pôde ser feita porque o computador de destino
>   as recusou activamente 127.0.0.1:25426]
>      System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +6604828
>      System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +249
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +606    System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +64
>
> [HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    ClientMvcProdutos.Controllers.<Index>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ClientMvcProdutos\ClientMvcProdutos\Controllers\ProdutosController.cs:25
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +92
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task)
>   +42    System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +73
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +37
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +68
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>   +69    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>   +230    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +68
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +42    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +124
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +30
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +30
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +30
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +21    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +24
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +30
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +29    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +23
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +129

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3446](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0)

Comment: Yes, your service application needs to be running on your machine first and listening on port 25426. Then run your client application. Can you reach the service with the browser?

Comment: how can i run the service in the visual studio 2015 i just pressed run with browser and then i need to stop it so i can run the application mvc. how can i do it?

Comment: How is this set up? Do you have two separate solutions or are both client and server apps in the same solution?

Comment: i created a rest api, and then i created a mvc project in the mvc project i set a helper that basicly set the connection to my service

Comment: 2 different solutions

Comment: You can run both MVC and api services on different ports simultaneously. Since they are in different solutions just F5 both.

Comment: sorry about my newbie question, but i need to stop 1 to run the other i cant run 2 applications at the same time :S

Comment: i did it thanks, :)