# Android studio ADB error 10061 over wifi connection

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

When I try to connect HTC U Ultra to `Android Studio` I get error:

```
unable to connect to <ip addr>:5555: cannot connect to <ip addr>:5555: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

I connect it using below command:

```
adb connect <ip addr>
```

Device and PC are on same network and I set port number to `5555`. I don't have this problem on Samsung Grand Prime and only HTC with android version 8 refuses connection.
On Samsung device when attempting to connect I get a permission dialog but HTC shows nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3446](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0)

Comment: @ishita-sinha I read all of them before. No one worked!