# SSL integration with Cloud SQL instance based MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I enabled `SSL` in a `MySQL Cloud SQL` instance. In order to connect to the instance , I downloaded the necessary certficates and can connect fine using `mysql` command. The `CloudSQL instance` is running with `Private IP` on a `sharedVPC` network .

```
   $ mysql -h 192.168.0.3 --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem -u testuser -p
    Enter password:
```

Now to test connectivity from a code to connect to `SQL` instance I deployed the following in `Cloud Functions`

```
  import pymysql
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine

  def sql_connect(request):
       engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://testuser:<password>@192.168.0.3/mysql',echo=True)
       tab = engine.execute('show databases;')
       return str([t[0] for t in tab])
```

It shows "Access Denied" error as shown below

```
  Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details:
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for testuser'@'192.168.60.4' (using password: YES)")
```

When I disable `SSL` it works fine as shown below

```
  ['information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sys', 'testdb']
```

A) To enable `SSL` in code I did the following

```
   ssl_args = {'sslrootcert':'server-ca.pem','sslcert':'client-cert.pem','sslkey':'client-key.pem'}  
   engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://testuser:<password>@192.168.0.3/mysql',echo=True,connect_args=ssl_args)
```

but it is failing with below error

```
 __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sslrootcert'
```

B) Also tried disabling `ssl=False` in code but it is failing with below error

```
  Invalid argument(s) 'ssl' sent to create_engine(), using configuration MySQLDialect_pymysql/QueuePool/Engine
```

UPDATE:

Changed the code for SSL as follows:

1. ```
   ssl_args = {'ssl': {'ca':'./server-ca.pem', 'cert':'./client-cert.pem', 'key':'./client-key.pem'}}
   ```
2. Uploaded the certs to `cloud function` source
3. Added `0.0.0.0/0` as `authorized networks` in `CloudSQL` to allow connecting from `Cloud functions`

Now seeing the following error

```
   "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.181' ([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'X.X.X.181'. (_ssl.c:1091))") . However can connect using the same certificates using `mysql` command
```

Need help to resolve both A) fixing the error as observed so that the code is integrated with `SSL` and B) Modify code so that it does not uses `SSL`

Comment: Hello,

So about the first error, I think the error is how are you referencing the certificates in the configuration, after looking at this two posts ( [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685852/sqlalchemy-pymysql-error-while-connecting-to-rds-using-iam-token-init-go) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989887/how-do-i-configure-pymysql-connect-for-ssl) ), this seems to be the problem to the first part of the post (you need to use a dict), although I could not find nothing from the second part, I think it could be a similar issue that is a reference issue.

Comment: Added more details . Now the error is different

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssl_ca` for the root, `ssl_cert` for the cert and `ssl_key` for the key

```
   ssl_args = {'ssl_ca':'server-ca.pem','ssl_cert':'client-cert.pem','ssl_key':'client-key.pem'}  
   engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://testuser:<password>@192.168.0.3/mysql',echo=True,connect_args=ssl_args)
```

Comment: Still the same error.. "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_ca'"

Answer (score 0):

Use SSL parameter in the form `ssl = {"ssl":{"ca":"server-ca.pem"}}` within the connect function

```
from pymysql import connect
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='mysql+pymysql://testuser:<password>@192.168.0.3/mysql?ssl_ca=server-ca.pem'

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

args, kwargs = engine.dialect.create_connect_args(engine.url)

# Create connection to the DB
db_conn = connect(kwargs["host"], kwargs["user"], kwargs["passwd"], kwargs["db"], ssl = {"ssl":{"ca":kwargs["ssl"]["ca"]}})

cursor = db_conn.cursor()

# Execute query
cursor.execute("show tables")

cursor.fetchall()
```