# Not able to connect to mysql using python

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I am not able to connect to mysql using python. I have installed mysql-connector but not able to connect Please review my code and let me know where to make a change

I have gone through search engines but couldn't find a solution

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

mydb = mysql.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",

 )
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> "C:\Users\varma\OneDrive\Documents\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py",
>
> line 529, in open_connection
>       self.sock.connect(sockaddr) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> "C:/Users/varma/OneDrive/Documents/try.py", line 6, in 
>       password="",   File "C:\Users\varma\OneDrive\Documents\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector__init__.py",
>
> line 173, in connect
>       return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\varma\OneDrive\Documents\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>
> line 104, in **init**
>       self.connect(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\varma\OneDrive\Documents\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py",
>
> line 780, in connect
>       self._open_connection()   File "C:\Users\varma\OneDrive\Documents\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>
> line 284, in _open_connection
>       self._socket.open_connection()   File "C:\Users\varma\OneDrive\Documents\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py",
>
> line 532, in open_connection
>       errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err))) mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it)

Comment: Looks like same error as below issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0