# Installing rabbitmq through my wix installer and creating new user and host failed

Tags: wix, erlang

We install Erlang 22.3 and RabbitMQ 3.83 through Wix Installer. This installer runs redistributable from Erlang and rabbitMQ and then use the custom actions to create the host and user. While doing so we get the error :

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
> the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
> remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it
> 127.0.0.1:15672

The problem we realised was it gets the different value for Erlang cookie on the locations - `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile` and `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%`.

Another observation is even though the Erlang cookies are different, the host and user get created on few VMs on the other hand even if the Erlang cookie is same the user does not get created few VMs. On a separate note both all these VMs are installed from same image.

Comment: [Maybe read this answer and have a check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695442/129130)? Firewall seems likely, but probably the first thing you checked? A little bit unclear what you are actually doing. You are automating this on many virtuals? Are they up to date with runtimes?

Comment: 15672 is the management ui, you need to enable it after installation. Is this done by a custom action as well?