# Load balanced WCF call to another WCF fails with 401.2 when same server is called

Tags: wcf, load-balancing, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

We have many WCF services on servers that are load balanced.
Lets say:

Balancer.domain.com

- server1.domain.com (2012R2)
- server2.domain.com (2012R2)

**WCF1** references **WCF2**.

There is no prob with calling except situations when:

client calls **balancer.domain.com/WCF1** that calls **balancer.doman.com/WCF2**

When the balancer eventually resolves the call like:

**server1**.domain.com/WCF1 -> **server1**.domain.com/WCF2 (call to same server)

**The connection is always refused with 401.2**

So far no solution found except direct referencing serverX addresses in WCFx configs (omitting balanced addresses).

*Can under these circumstances help setting registry - BackConnectionHostNames ?*

If so, what is the correct formulation for each serverX, please?
(since it is massively called production env. I'd like to have solid confirmations before any registry changes)

Comment: If you want to try `BackConnectionHostNames`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0/75772584#75772584) answer. The setting takes a list of URLs. You would specify the WCF service URLs that should be accessible from the local server, both the balancer URL and the internal URL.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I forgot to put solution here. In my case naming the balanced name was the solution. Like balancer.domain.com.