# AddressAccessDeniedException "Your process does not have access rights to this namespace" when Unit testing WCF service

Tags: wcf

I am testing my WCF services but I need to fake the behavior because my services are bootstrapped using a custom factory.
This is the code I wrote for my test:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDomainWriteService>(
   new CustomBinding(
      new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(), 
      new HttpTransportBindingElement()),
   new EndpointAddress(new Uri("local")));
var service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

And I have a test initialize which is creating a new ServiceHost:

```
internal static void StartService()
{
    Instance = new ServiceHost(typeof (DomainWriteService));
    Instance.Open();
}
```

I have configured a fake endpoint in my MsTest project in the following way:

```
<service name="xxx.DomainWriteService">
  <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
    name="local" bindingName="http" contract="xxx.IDomainWriteService" />
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://xxx/service" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

But when I run my tests I get this runtime error:

```
    Class Initialization method xxx.ClassInitialize threw exception. System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: 
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: 
HTTP could not register URL **http://+:80/service/**. 
Your process does not have access rights to this namespace 
(see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). ---> 
System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied.
```

I am on Windows 8

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use `netsh add urlacl` to allow access for the process listening to be able to receive on port 80, (or share port 80 with other listeners)

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/service user=YOURUSER
```

Where `YOURUSER` is the credentials of the process running the listener, e.g. `DOMAIN\User`.

See also: [WCF ServiceHost access rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885744/wcf-servicehost-access-rights)

Comment: Heads up that the trailing slash will matter when registering, otherwise yo'll get an Error 87:

netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:12345/ user=domain\username

Note the / at the end of the 12345!