# Starting service automatically after installation

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

This is a Windows Service project using VS2015 and .NET Framework 4.5.

I'm trying to install my service through a post-build action and then start it automatically by using `ServiceController.Start()`. Here's my code that tries to start the service:

```
private void ProjectInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
  using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))
  {
    using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
    {
      try
      {
        sw.Write("Starting service...");
        sc.Start();
        sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        sw.Write("Service status is now set to {0}.", sc.Status.ToString());
      }
      catch (InvalidOperationException)
      {
        sw.Write("Could not start the service.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The service installs just fine, but my `ServiceController.WaitForStatus()` call seemingly keeps waiting forever. I have tried calling it from `Committed` and `AfterInstall` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out finally. My `Start()` call was actually failing, which I didn't notice until I went to Event Viewer. The error message was something like:

```
Your process does not have access rights to this namespace
```

Googling for the error message brought up [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885744/wcf-servicehost-access-rights) where the accepted answer did the trick for me. Hope this helps someone down the road.