# Getting HTTP Get Error while Consuming WCF Service hosted in Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

While Trying to consume a  WCF service hosted in a windows service getting HTTP Get Error,  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.But when I host Same application in a console application its working fine. The issue is getting when application hosting in Windows service.Following code is using to host service.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
        try
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/AuditService/");


            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(AuditService), baseAddress);


            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAuditService), new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None), baseAddress);

            host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            host.Abort();

        }
}
```

Comment: Check if this works : http://www.csharptutorial.in/30/csharp-net-how-to-consume-wcf-service-hosted-as-window-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the port is opened?

You can check this using telnet client

```
telnet machine 8080
```

If the port is not opened then you can check the exception details to see what is wrong.

If your HTTP-based service is started under non-administrator account then most likely you need to register it with the command like the following

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/AuditService user=mylocaluser
```

You can find more details here [WCF ServiceHost access rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885744/wcf-servicehost-access-rights)

Comment: executed the following command: netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/AuditService user="NETWORK SERVICE". Now its working. But have simple query, so this url  registration not needed if the service is installed using admin account?

Answer (score 0):

You open command prompt with administrator and write this text:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/AuditService user=Everyone
```