# WCF with HTTP on dynamic port number

Tags: http, wcf, urlacl

I have a need to do automated testing of a configuration of WCF bindings. I wrote a test that, in it setup, picks a random port number and binds to it with a `WSHttpBinding`. The test runs a `ServiceHost` for the duration of its execution and then shuts it down. This works, but then when the build agents try to run the test, I get this error:

`System.Exception: Unable to set up service host ---> System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:52361/Test/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied`

Is there any way to work around this? Can this "urlacl" mechanism be disabled??

UPDATE: This was a wild goose chase, as it turns out. This *wasn't* the error that was happening on the build agents. I flubbed it when gathering that information. Turns out the build agents are running elevated and don't run into the `urlacl` problem. The actual problem I was encountering was that a NuGet reference somehow hadn't had its corresponding assembly reference added to the .csproj file. How the tests worked locally, I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

The error is "The process does not have permission to access this namespace".
You can try the following methods.

- Make `Test` public
- Run the service as administrator
- Run the command prompt as administrator, add URL to ACL `netsh http add urlacl url=`

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/441371/When-Hosting-the-WCF-service-i-got-exception

[WCF ServiceHost access rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885744/wcf-servicehost-access-rights)